# Interaction between GADTs and ScopedTypeVariables/PatternSignatures

Tags: haskell, gadt, scoped-type-variables

I'm exploring the 'hackneyed' example of length-indexed vectors, code adapted from [Richard Eisenberg's thesis](https://richarde.dev/papers/2016/thesis/eisenberg-thesis.pdf) section 3.1

```
{-# LANGUAGE  GADTs, TypeFamilies, DataKinds, KindSignatures,
              TypeOperators, ScopedTypeVariables  #-}
                          -- PatternSignatures  -- deprecated

import GHC.Types (Type)

data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat
data Vec :: Type -> Nat -> Type  where
  Nil :: Vec a Zero                       -- E has 'Zero
  (:>) :: a -> Vec a n -> Vec a (Succ n)  -- E has 'Succ
infixr 5 :>

type family (+) (n :: Nat) (m :: Nat) :: Nat  where
  (+) Zero      m = m
  (+) (Succ n') m = Succ (n' + m)

append :: Vec a n -> Vec a m -> Vec a (n + m)
append (Nil     :: Vec aa Zero) (w :: Vec aa mm) = w :: Vec aa (Zero + mm)
append (x :> (v :: Vec a n'))   (w :: Vec a m)   = x :> ((append v w) :: Vec a (n' + m))
```

The `append Nil ...` equation is rejected (GHC 8.6.5)

```
* Couldn't match type `m' with `n + m'
  `m' is a rigid type variable bound by
    the type signature for:
      append :: forall a (n :: Nat) (m :: Nat).
                Vec a n -> Vec a m -> Vec a (n + m)
    at ...
  Expected type: Vec a (n + m)
    Actual type: Vec a ('Zero + m)
```

Giving the result type as `:: Vec aa mm` is also rejected.

```
  Expected type: Vec a (n + m)
    Actual type: Vec a m
```

weird because that's accepted (see below).

What I'm really trying to do is use `PatternSignatures` for the arguments to `append`. But that extension is deprecated, I have to use `ScopedTypeVariables`. And that means the tyvars from the signature for `append` are in scope in the equations. So I've used fresh tyvar names.

The GADT gives `Nil :: Vec a Zero`, so I give that as its pattern signature (with a fresh `aa`). But it seems GHC can't unify the `n` from `append`'s signature with the `Zero`. If I change that equation to either of these, all is happy:

```
append (Nil     :: Vec aa nn) (w :: Vec aa mm) = w :: Vec aa (nn + mm)

append (Nil     :: Vec aa nn) (w :: Vec aa mm) = w :: Vec aa (mm)
```

To validate those, GHC must be figuring out that `Nil :: Vec a Zero` and that `Zero + m = m` from the type family equation for `+`. So why is it grumpy about the pattern signature with `Zero`?

(I was originally trying to give the equations for `append` purely with `PatternSignatures`, to see if GHC could infer the signature. That didn't get off the ground.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing to notice is that the error you're showing is not the only error you're getting, and actually, it's not the important one.  The other error you should see is:

```
    * Couldn't match type `n' with 'Zero
      `n' is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          append :: forall a (n :: Nat) (m :: Nat).
                    Vec a n -> Vec a m -> Vec a (n + m)
        at ...
      Expected type: Vec a n
        Actual type: Vec a 'Zero
    * When checking that the pattern signature: Vec a 'Zero
        fits the type of its context: Vec a n
      In the pattern: Nil :: Vec a Zero
```

The key part here is "When checking that the pattern signature fits the type of its context".  Indeed, the type of the pattern `Nil` is not simply `Vec a Zero`; it's actually something like `() => (n ~ Zero) => Vec a n`.  This type says that the pattern *may* match on anything of the type `Vec a n`, and *if* it matches, then the constraint `n ~ Zero` is brought into scope.  On the other hand, a pattern with the type `Vec a Zero` is type-restricted to only be applicable to types `Vec a Zero`.  In your definition of `append`, the input has type `Vec a n`, so a pattern of type `Vec a Zero` won't match.

(You can read more about pattern synonym types, which may be enlightening, [in the docs](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#typing-of-pattern-synonyms).)

---

This may be easier to see with an even simpler example and the use of pattern synonyms.

Consider this type and function:

```hs
data Foo a where
  Bar :: Foo Int
  Baz :: Foo Char

doFoo :: Foo a -> a
doFoo Bar = 1
doFoo Baz = 'c'
```

All is well.  But, if we change the sixth line to

```hs
doFoo (Bar :: Foo Int) = 1
```

then we will get an error very much like the one you're seeing in `append`.  Let's play around with pattern synonyms now.  What if we had a pattern synonym around `Bar` with the simple type `Foo Int`:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms #-}
pattern BarInt :: Foo Int
pattern BarInt = Bar
```

If we use that in `doFoo`, we get the same error that the pattern type doesn't match.  This really does make sense, because this pattern is only defined for inputs of type `Foo Int` and not generically on `Foo a`.  Let's try another variation:

```hs
pattern BarA :: Foo a
pattern BarA <- Bar
```

Note the use of `<-` here instead of `=`, making this a unidirectional pattern synonym instead of a bidirectional one.  We must do this because while we can "forget" about `Int` and go from a `Foo Int` to a `Foo a`, we cannot do the reverse.  But, what happens if we try using `BarA` in `doFoo`?  Now we get an error like this:

```
    * Couldn't match expected type `a' with actual type `Int'
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          dofoo :: forall a. Foo a -> a
```

This pattern is loose enough to be accepted, but after the pattern match, we still have no knowledge about `a`, so we can't return an `Int`.

To really recreate the `Bar` pattern, we'd need to write:

```
pattern Bar' :: () => (a ~ Int) => Foo a
pattern Bar' = Bar
```

Here, our pattern type indicates that there is no restriction ahead of time to applying the pattern (the initial `() =>`), after the match we'll know `a ~ Int`, and this pattern can match on anything of the form `Foo a`.

Comment: Thank you, perfect answer. Yes I did get the message re rigid type variable, apologies I should have shown that in the q. I hadn't realised there's `PatternSynonyms` lurking in the background with a GADT. That double `=>` is a quantified/implication constraint, I think(?)